# Output audio through two bluetooth devices at the same time with one bluetooth adapter

Tags: 18.04, sound, kubuntu, bluetooth

The devices I have in mind are a bluetooth headset and a bluetooth speaker in Kubuntu 18.04 with the integrated laptop bluetooth.

Is it possible to *use* two different bluetooth sound output devices at the same time? (I mean on the same bluetooth adapter, the one that comes with the laptop, without adding a second one.)

I know multiple bluetooth devices can be added, paired and even connected, but can they be *used* at the same time?

I want to be able to *play* sound at the same time in a bluetooth external speaker and in a bluetooth headset.

I can make them list as connected in Kubuntu 18.04 bluetooth settings, but in fact I have to disconnect one to be able to use the other. I cannot make them appear at the same time in the list of sound output devices.

Can I try to use them both or is it not possible?

I read [here](https://superuser.com/a/935508/162573) that different *profiles* may be needed, but I see no such setting and I don't know what those are.

Comment: I would really like to know whether this is at all possible. My android phone can do this easily (samsung), but it might require some custom hardware or software not available on average laptops or desktop linux....

Comment: You *could* take a look at the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791992/connect-and-use-multiple-bluetooth-dongles-on-linux)